# Problema para remover espaço após quebra de linha

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    int x,y,i;

    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%d",&y);

    if ((x<y)&&(x>1)&&(x<20)&&(y<10000)){
        for (i=1;i<=x;i++){
            printf("%d ",i);
                }
            printf("\n");
       for (i=(x+1);i<=y;i++){
           printf("%d ",i);
       }
   }
 return 0;
}
```

objetivo do programa:

***1º: O programa lê dois números X e Y 
(X menor Y). A seguir mostra uma sequência 
de 1 a Y, passando para a 
próxima linha a cada X números.***

***2º: Cada sequência deverá ser impressa em uma linha, 
com um espaço em branco entre cada número.***

***3º: A entrada contém dois números inteiros X (maior que 1 e menor que 20) e Y (maior que X e menor que 100000) respectivamente.***

***4º:OBS: O programa não precisar ter resposta para os casos em que o programa não roda, e também não precisa de interação com o usuário.***

***Exemplo demonstrando o erro do meu programa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: saida esperada com as entradas 8-16]

***Removendo esse ultimo espaço antes da quebra de cada linha o problema da questão sera solucionado, só não encontro uma forma de fazer isso.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu programa exibe a sequência de `1 a X`, porém, o enunciado da questão não diz nada sobre exibir essa sequência! Qual dos dois está correto?

Para identificar valores de `Y` que sejam múltiplos de `X` basta verificar se o resto da divisão (ou [módulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) de `Y` por `X` é igual a zero, veja só:

```
if( y % x == 0 )
    printf( "Y eh multiplo de X!\n" );
```

Seguindo o seu raciocínio e o enunciado da questão, segue uma solução comentada:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int i,x,y;

    /* 1) O programa le dois numeros X e Y (X menor Y)... */
    printf("X: ");
    scanf( "%d", &x );

    printf("Y: ");
    scanf( "%d", &y );

    /*
        3) A entrada contem dois numeros inteiros X (maior que 1 e menor que 20) e
           Y (maior que X e menor que 100000) respectivamente.
    */
    if( (x<y) && (x>1) && (x < 20) && (y < 10000) )
    {
        /* 1) A seguir mostra uma sequencia de 1 a Y... */
        for ( i = 1; i <= y; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d", i );

            /* 1) Passando para a proxima linha a cada X numeros... */
            /* ...e passando pra ultima linha na ultima iteracao    */
            if( (i % x == 0) || (i == y) )
                printf("\n");
            else
                printf(" "); /* Pulo do gato! */
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* 4) OBS: O programa nao precisar ter resposta para os casos em que o programa nao roda */
        printf("Entrada invalida!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Teste (`X=19` e `Y=60`):

```
X: 19
Y: 60
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57
58 59 60
```

Teste (`X=3` e `Y=17`):

```
X: 3
Y: 17
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17
```

Teste (`X=4` e `Y=15`):

```
X: 4
Y: 15
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15
```

Teste (`X=2` e `Y=8`):

```
X: 2
Y: 8
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

Comment: Caro Lacobus, obrigado pela ajuda no código... Que ajuste eu posso fazer nesse código que você fez baseado no meu para que não fique 2 espaços entre cada numero e fique apenas 1 espaço?

Comment: Feito! Veja se atende.

Comment: Muito obrigado Lacobus, você me ajudou muito ---  Só existe uma situação que o programa esta acusando "resposta vazia", de 7 testes ele passou em 6. Irei realizar alguns testes manualmente e tentar encontrar essa falha no programa.

Comment: @Erick: que situação é essa ?

Comment: o erro ocorria na seguinte situação x:1 , y=10 devido a essa linha de código - if( (x<y) && (x>1) && (x < 20) && (y < 10000) ) //porem o erro não era meu o seu, e sim do enunciado do problema que dizia que x tinha que ser maior que 1 , logo não faz sentido ter x=1 como teste do problema... - mudei a linha de código citada acima em - if( (x<y) && (x>=1) && (x <=20) && (y < 10000) ) e o problema foi sanado.

Answer (score 1):

Trate o primeiro como uma exceção que não tem um espaço, o resto vai tudo dentro do normal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    if (x < y && x > 1 && x < 20 && y < 10000) {
         printf("%d", 1);
        for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) printf(" %d", i);
        printf("\n%d", x + 1);
        for (int i = x + 2; i <= y; i++) printf(" %d", i);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wCLf9V). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/myubvnrj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Cleaning.c).

Dá para fazer o inverso e tratar o último como exceção, mas eu não gosto.

Comment: Ajustei o código dessa forma e consegui, mas tem um problema, na primeira linha fica correta, mas para valores maiores ex:(x=10,y=50) o código não esta pulando linhas. Como posso ajustar para que fique genérico ? -  Porque se eu colocar x=10,y=20 o código fica certinho, mas como dito anteriormente para valores maiores de y a exibição fica errada.